# Bar plot based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have generated the dataframe below, I want to plot a bar plot where the x-axis will have two categories i.e. exp_type values and the y-axis will have a value of avg. Then a legend of disk_type for each type of disk.

```
      exp_type disk_type          avg
0  Random Read      nvme  3120.240000
1  Random Read       sda   132.638831
2  Random Read       sdb   174.313413
3     Seq Read      nvme  3137.849000
4     Seq Read       sda   119.171269
5     Seq Read       sdb   211.451616
```

I have attempted to use the code below for the plotting but I get the wrong plot. They should be grouped together with links.

```
def plot(df):
    df.plot(x='exp_type', y=['avg'], kind='bar')
    print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Use seaborn. `import seaborn as sns; sns.barplot(x='exp_type', y='avg', hue='disk_type', data=your_df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here is to reshape correctly your dataframe with `pivot`:

```
(df.pivot(index='disk_type', columns='exp_type', values='avg').rename_axis(columns='Exp Type')
   .plot(kind='bar', rot=0, title='Performance', xlabel='Disk Type', ylabel='IOPS'))

# OR

(df.pivot(index='exp_type', columns='disk_type', values='avg').rename_axis(columns='Disk Type')
   .plot(kind='bar', rot=0, title='Performance', xlabel='Exp Type', ylabel='IOPS'))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Update**

Pandas doesn't understand how to group data because you have a flatten dataframe (one numeric value per row). You have to reshape it:

```
>>> df.pivot(index='exp_type', columns='disk_type', values='avg')

exp_type   Random Read     Seq Read  # <- Two bar groups
disk_type                          
nvme       3120.240000  3137.849000  # <- First bar of each group
sda         132.638831   119.171269  # <- Second bar of each group
sdb         174.313413   211.451616  # <- Third bar of each group
```

Comment: Awesome and +1 for even understanding the context of what I am working on by guessing the axis. IOPS should be Bandwidth but that's not very important. I will do more reading about what pivot is all about.

Comment: Also, would have been nice to add a brief explanation of why pivot would solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I added some comment about pivot and how plot understand a dataframe. (and sorry for bandwith :-))